# For the function given parametrically x(θ) = 4sin (θ) and y(θ) = 2cos(θ) show that dy/dx=-x/4y

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Steps so far:

x= 4 sin(θ) y=2cos(θ)

dy/dx=(dy/dθ)/(dx/dθ)

dy/dθ=-2sin(θ)

dx/dθ=4cos(θ)

dy/dx=-2sin(θ)/4cos(θ)

Comment: Then substitute $\sin\theta = \dfrac{x}{4}$ and $\cos \theta = \dfrac y2$...

Comment: After I substitute then I simplify and I have gotten my final answer?

Answer (score 1):

From here, you know that y = 2cos($\theta$) and x = 4sin($\theta$) so

-2sin($\theta$) = $\frac{-x}{2}$

4cos($\theta$) = 2y

$\frac{-2sin(\theta)}{4cos(\theta)}=\frac{\frac{-x}{2}}{2y} = \frac{-x}{4y}$